# Is the concept of "Regression toward the mean" closely related to Power Analysis?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-power

**Regression toward the mean** says that if a measurement is extreme at first, it will gradually tend towards the average value in subsequent measurements.

Isn't this what Power analysis all about? Why aren't these two terms brought up together as frequent? Power analysis seems to solve all problems associated with regression toward the mean.

Comment: I am not sure I follow you... Power has largely to do with sampling and variability, whereas regression to the mean concerns the fact that, on average, cases tend to be close to the average, and not to the extremes.

Comment: If I take a low sample size (say a sample size of 2), well these observations could be extrema. I would need more observations such that they regress towards the mean. I could approximate the amount of observations that I need by using power analysis

Comment: (-1) This is a problematic characterization of regression to the mean.  It is just bizarre to assert that power analysis, which is a concept and procedure wholly independent of regression to the mean, will "solve all problems" associated with the latter.  This is one more example of a spate of questions you have posed that assert strange, false things and as such appear to reflect no research.

Comment: I am sorry about that.  I (and others) have been trying to convey that message tactfully and gently for many days, but it hasn't been getting across.  I'm having to process a great deal of flags complaining about the low quality of your questions.  Please consider slowing down, working to write higher quality questions, waiting for answers, and reflecting on them before proceeding to write large numbers of questions that require substantial time and attention from the community.

Comment: Zero, you posted 6 questions in the last half an hour; this is clearly opposite to what @whuber asked you to consider, so your apology does not appear sincere.

Comment: zero, your response here was inappropriate, suggesting you didn't take the comment you replied to seriously. You're quick to complain others are hurtful when pointing out genuine problems with your activities, but your own responses to others are themselves more problematic. I suggest that instead of responding to comments with comments, you simply act on their suggestions (whether direct or implied); try to only respond to comments either to answer a direct question (and only if it cannot be answered in an edit to your question), or to seek to clarify what was intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a broad question that I would answer by a no.

### Regression to the mean is about interpretation fallacy of a test result

Regression to the mean is primarily a phenomenon that consists in observing that an extreme event is likely to be associated with a less extreme future event. This phenomenon can be the cause of many badly designed inductions leading to wrong interpretations. I remember an enlightening example from the book "Think fast, think slow" by D. Kahneman. During a lecture of his to flight instructors on rewarding students being much more effective than blaming them when teaching, an instructor in the audience told him of his experience that when he rewards a student for excellent performance, the next performance was generally not an improvement, while when another is blamed for a bad performance, that student generally does better afterwards. The observation was mostly due to the regression to the mean effect: performances are subject to random perturbations and an extreme one is more likely to be followed by a less extreme one. (I do not have the book at hand but remember  its words as enlightening (and more generally I really enjoyed the book).)

More generally, one can imagine a standardized experiment, where one group is people with good performance (G1) and another with people with bad performance (G2) to see whether they will improve on their next performance.  Why not? If all students have the same performance on average (with independent realisations),  then the test will conclude that G1 got worse and that G2 got better (on average). The test is valid but the interpretation of its result may be wrong if one does not care about the regression to the mean effect.

### Power analysis is about minimal sample size to conclusive test

Power analysis is dedicated to control type 2 error when testing an hypothesis having built the groups whatever they are. And they may be wrongly built cause of the regression to the mean phenomenon! 
So the two concepts are pretty different.